no instance of overloaded function std::max matches the argument list
So i got 2 warnings:
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::max" matches the argument list
Error   C2672   'std::max': no matching overloaded function found
How do I fix this? Thanks for answering!
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<algorithm>
int main()
{
    unsigned long long a{}, b{}, c{}, ab{}, bc{}, ac{}, abc{};
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> ab >> bc >> ac >> abc;

    unsigned int temp{};

    temp = std::max(a, b, c, ab, bc, abc, ac);
    abc = temp;

    if (a + b == ab)
    {
        a = ab - b;
        b = ab - a;
    }

    else if (a + b == ac)
    {
        a = ac - b;
        b = ac - a;
    }

    else if (a + b == bc)
    {
        a = bc - a;
        b = bc - a;
    }

    c = abc - a - b;
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " ";
}


Dupe: How to include multiple variables in max() function?

Minor point: get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing unsigned int temp{}; temp = std::max(...); to unsigned int temp = std::max(...);. Also, most folks would write unsigned temp...; the int isn't needed.

Off topic: This code is strange. If a + b == ab, then ab - b must be equal to a and the assignment a = ab - b does not change a.

There are no variadic std::max overload, but there is one overload taking initializer list:
const auto temp = std::max({a, b, c, ab, bc, abc, ac});

